Could not find a circleci can not find version that satisfies the requirement pipenv==2021.5.29
I can not figure this out I am trying to deploy a project from git to circleci but any time I try sending a new pull request and send it will have an error
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv==2021.5.29 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pipenv==2021.5.29
and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
WARNING: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib?
Installed Python-3.6.3 to /root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3

pyenv global 3.6.3

pyenv rehash


it will give me this error in the build_docker_image:Build docker image and if I ignore it and try and deploy it to qa or production it will fail.
here is the config.yml file code:
  version: 2.1
  orbs:
    aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@2.0.6
    aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@7.3.0

  # CircleCI needs variables:
  # AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_ECR_ID, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  # PROD_TARGET_GROUP, STAGING_TARGET_GROUP, QA_TARGET_GROUP, CIRCLECI_SG_ID

  jobs:
    build_docker_image:
      machine:
          image: ubuntu-2004:202111-02
      steps:
        - checkout
        - aws-cli/install
        - run:
            name: install python 3.6.3
            command: |
              pyenv install 3.6.3
              pyenv global 3.6.3
        - run:
            name: Installing dependencies
            command: |
              set -ex
              sudo apt-get update
              sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python-setuptools python-dev
              sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev libjpeg-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev
              sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
              pip install --upgrade pip
              sudo update-ca-certificates
              pip install --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ pipenv==2021.5.29
              pip install boto3
              pipenv install --system
        
        - run:
            name: Pulling environment variables
            command: |
              if [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == 'production' ]; then
                export ENV=production
              elif [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == 'staging' ]; then
                export ENV=staging
              else
                export ENV=qa
              fi
              bash ./deployment/circleci/pull-variables ${ENV}
              echo "export ENV=$ENV" >> $BASH_ENV
        - run:
            name: Declaration environmnets
            command: |
                echo "export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}')" >> $BASH_ENV
        - run :
            name: Add circleci IP to SG
            command: |
              export public_ip_address=$(wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com)
              echo got ip $public_ip_address
              aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}" --group-id "${CIRCLECI_SG_ID}" --protocol tcp --port 5432 --cidr "$public_ip_address"/32 || exit 1
              echo Added IP to SG
        - run:
            name: Building static files
            command: |
              sed -i "s@credentials_key_id@${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}@" .boto
              sed -i "s@credentials_secret_key@${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS}@" .boto
              if [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == 'production' ]; then
                export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}') && export AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=production-blue-manor-education-static && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py compress --force
              elif [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == 'staging' ]; then
                export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}') && export AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=staging-blue-manor-education-static && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py compress --force
              elif [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == 'qa' ]; then
                export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}') && export AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=qa-blue-manor-education-static && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py compress --force
              else
                echo 'This script is for production, staging, qa branches only'
              fi 
        - run :
            name: Delete circleci IP from SG
            when: always
            command: |
              export public_ip_address=$(wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com)
              aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}" --group-id "${CIRCLECI_SG_ID}" --protocol tcp --port 5432 --cidr "$public_ip_address"/32
              echo IP removed  
        - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
            checkout: false
            attach-workspace: true
            account-url: AWS_ECR_ID
            dockerfile: deployment/circleci/Dockerfile
            path: .
            repo: "${ENV}-blue-manor-education"
            region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            tag: "backend-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}"
        - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
            checkout: false
            attach-workspace: true
            account-url: AWS_ECR_ID
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
            path: deployment/circleci
            repo: "${ENV}-blue-manor-education"
            region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            tag: "nginx-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}"
        - persist_to_workspace:
              root: ./
              paths:
                - ./

    unit_tests:
        docker:
          - image: cimg/python:3.6
        steps:
          - checkout
          - aws-cli/install
          - setup_remote_docker
          - attach_workspace:
              at: ./
          - run:
              name: Declaration environmnets
              command: |
                  echo "export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}')" >> $BASH_ENV
          - run:
              name: Run unit-tests
              no_output_timeout: 30m
              command: |
                  sed -i "s@TAG@${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}@" deployment/circleci/testing/docker-compose.yml
                  sed -i "s@AWS_ECR_ID@${AWS_ECR_ID}@" deployment/circleci/testing/docker-compose.yml
                  sed -i "s@ENV@${ENVIRONMENT}@" deployment/circleci/testing/docker-compose.yml
                  cd deployment/circleci/testing && bash run-tests $ENVIRONMENT $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

    delete_docker_images:
      machine:
        enabled: true
      steps:
        - checkout
        - aws-cli/install
        - run:
            name: Deleting the docker image
            command: |
              if !([ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "production" ] || [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "qa" ] || [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "staging" ])
              then
                echo 'Deleting images for test branches'
                aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name "qa-blue-manor-education" --image-ids imageTag=backend-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7} --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name "qa-blue-manor-education" --image-ids imageTag=nginx-${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7} --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              fi

    database_migrations:
      docker:
        - image: cimg/python:3.6
      steps:
        - checkout
        - aws-cli/install
        - setup_remote_docker
        - attach_workspace:
            at: ./
        - run:
            name: Declaration environmnets
            command: |
                echo "export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}')" >> $BASH_ENV
        - run:
            name: Running database migrations
            no_output_timeout: 30m
            command: |
                sed -i "s@TAG@${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}@" deployment/circleci/migrations/docker-compose.yml
                sed -i "s@PROJECT_NAME@blue-manor-education@" deployment/circleci/migrations/docker-compose.yml
                sed -i "s@AWS_ECR_ID@${AWS_ECR_ID}@" deployment/circleci/migrations/docker-compose.yml
                sed -i "s@ENV@${ENVIRONMENT}@" deployment/circleci/migrations/docker-compose.yml
                cd deployment/circleci/migrations && bash migration_master $ENVIRONMENT $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

    deploy:
      docker:
        - image: cimg/python:3.6
      steps:
        - checkout
        - attach_workspace:
            at: ./
        - run:
            name: Declaration environmnets
            command: |
                echo "export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}')" >> $BASH_ENV
        - run:
            name: Running deploy process
            no_output_timeout: 30m
            command: |
              sed -i "s@TAG@${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}@" deployment/circleci/docker-compose.yml
              sed -i "s@ENV@${ENVIRONMENT}@" deployment/circleci/docker-compose.yml
              sed -i "s@AWS_ECR_ID@${AWS_ECR_ID}@" deployment/circleci/docker-compose.yml
              curl -o ./ecs-cli https://amazon-ecs-cli.s3.amazonaws.com/ecs-cli-linux-amd64-latest
              chmod +x ./ecs-cli
              ./ecs-cli configure profile --access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --profile-name default
              ./ecs-cli configure --cluster $ENVIRONMENT-blue-manor-education --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --default-launch-type EC2
              ./ecs-cli compose -f deployment/circleci/docker-compose.yml --ecs-params deployment/circleci/ecs-params.yml --project-name "$ENVIRONMENT-blue-manor-education" \
                  service up --cluster-config default --target-group-arn ${TARGET_GROUP_ARN} --container-name nginx --container-port 8080 \
                  --role ecsServiceRole --force-deployment --timeout 30

  workflows:
    ci_cd:
      jobs:
        - build_docker_image
        - unit_tests:
            requires:
              - build_docker_image

        - delete_docker_images:
            requires:
              - unit_tests

        - database_migrations:
            requires:
              - delete_docker_images
            filters:
              branches:
                only:
                  - qa
                  - staging
                  - production

        - deploy:
            requires:
              - database_migrations
            filters:
              branches:
                only:
                  - qa
                  - staging
                  - production

I tried changing piping version and just getting rid of it and I asked chatgpt to see if it can do it and they all failed!.
